# Swift package manager for objective c code

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift-package-manager

I have few old objective c projects which has to be converted to a framework for usage across existing and new xcodeproj. Will SPM be a good choice ? Please let me know if SPM work for a pure objective c project ?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question?

Comment: Please accept the given answer or explain why it does not answer your question.

Answer (score 13):

Apple have now answered this question.

From the documentation
"Swift packages are reusable components of Swift, Objective-C, Objective-C++, C, or C++ code that developers can use in their projects"

So yes, and I intend to do this almost immediately, as the maintenance of frameworks has been a major pain over the years, with all the run scripts and the like.

Here is the link for the source document :
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages